# How to fix Pycharm Community importing error with authorisation with Gmail API?

Tags: python, gmail

I am newly discovered Gmail API and I plan to use it to send verification emails with Python as part of a project I am doing.

However, when looking through the documentation and attempting to authorise access as stated here (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python) as I attempt to install all the packages stated in the documentation, I am presented with 'installing packages failed' on Pycharm.

I have attempted to install google-api-python-client with Pycharm Community's terminal which worked, however the program still labels when the package is used as 'unknown references'.